# Data Reshaping for CNN using Keras

Tags: python, keras, reshape

I'm a beginner in Keras. I've loaded MNIST dataset in Keras and checked it's dimension.
The code is

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

# load data into train and test sets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print("Shape: ", X_train[0].shape)
```

And the output is

```
(60000, 28, 28, 1)
(60000, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(10000, 28, 28, 1)
(10000, 10, 2, 2)
Shape:  (28, 28, 1)
```

As X_train and X_test are already in the shape (#sample, width, height, #channel). Do we still need reshaping? Why?
The tutorial I'm following use the following reshaping code:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
```

My second question is that why is `.astype('float32')` is used in code?

Lastly, I could not understand the output of `print(y_train.shape)` and `print(y_test.shape)`.

Please suggest.
I've already read [Reshaping of data for deep learning using Keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/reshaping-of-data-for-deep-learning-using-keras) however still my doubts are unclear.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial? The `X_train` nad `X_test` reshapes you are doing are different that the reshapes done in the [Reshaping of data for deep learning using Keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/reshaping-of-data-for-deep-learning-using-keras)

Comment: This is a part of IBM'S Coursera class week 4 [ungraded assignment]. https://labs.cognitiveclass.ai/tools/jupyterlab/lab/tree/labs/DL0101EN/DL0101EN-4-1-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-with-Keras-py-v1.0.ipynb  The course is at https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-to-deep-learning-with-keras/home/welcome

Comment: Now, my concern is that datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/… mentions the desired shape to be (nb_samples, nb_channels, width, height) and the course, I'm following is doing it like (nb_samples, width, height,nb_channels). Why is it different?

Comment: I THINK this is because of an old Tensorflow convention. GPU input was one way, CPU input was another. I'll try to find a reference.

Comment: Sure, please share if you find some reference. Thanks again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774234/why-tensorflow-uses-channel-last-ordering-instead-of-row-major discusses the reason for the different order. Are all of your questions answered?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yeah, all my questions are answered. Your comments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1**
The reason for reshaping is to ensure that the input data to the model is in the correct shape. But you can say it using reshape is a replication of effort.

**Answer 2**
The reason for converting to float so that later we could normalize image between the range of 0-1 without loss of information.

Comment: 1. So, we can skip this step and just convert to float like X_train = X_train.astype('float32')? What do you say?

Comment: 2. If I'm not wrong, it means that if we don't convert integers to float there & then normalize it (or divide by 255), the resulting values would be coerced to be integer values so we may lose information. Please verify.

Comment: You can only omit 1 only when you intend to omit 2 as well. The only problem you would could face while omitting 1 and 2 would be slow convergence or maybe in some cases you would not converge.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. As mentioned I just want to omit to reshape as it was redundant and instead using  X_train = X_train.astype('float32') and X_test = X_test.astype('float32'). However, after re-running the same notebook this time I'm getting the shapes as mentioned by @from keras import michael. It's surpring for me too but those shape I was expecting earlier too, so finally I need reshaping  as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Now, my concer is that https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/reshaping-of-data-for-deep-learning-using-keras mentions the desired shape to be (nb_samples, nb_channels, width, height) and the course, I'm following is doing it like (nb_samples, width, height,nb_channels). Why is it different?

Comment: I am not sure maybe it has something to with your hosted environment etc.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get those shapes. Using your code, I get:

(60000, 28, 28)
(60000,)
(10000, 28, 28)
(10000,)
Shape:  (28, 28)

which makes more sense. For example, your output should not have 6 tensor dimensions: "(60000, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2)".

Comment: Does it depend on version? I'm using keras 2.2.5; which one is yours?

Comment: I was also surprised to see 6 tensor dimensions like "(60000, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2)". What is more surprising is that without making any change, I've just re-run the script & this time I got the same shapes as that of yours [which was expected result earlier too. Anyways, thanks.